# Output list of packages in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to export the list of packages installed on Anaconda Jupyter notebook.

`a = 'help('modules')`

`with open('output.txt , 'w') as f:` 
`f.write(str(a))`

This results in an output file with the text "None".

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)  from contextlib library to capture the standard output. The reason your code is not behaving as expected is because `help` doesn't return anything, it just "prints"

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        help('modules')
```

On Linux, you can also directly do `!conda list > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import types

def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__

excludes = ['builtins', 'types', 'sys']

imported_modules = [module for module in imports() if module not in excludes]

clean_modules = []

for module in imported_modules:

    sep = '.'  # to handle 'matplotlib.pyplot' cases
    rest = module.split(sep, 1)[0]
    clean_modules.append(rest)

changed_imported_modules = list(set(clean_modules))  # drop duplicates

pip_modules = !pip freeze  # you could also use `!conda list` with anaconda

for module in pip_modules:
    name, version = module.split('==')
    if name in changed_imported_modules:
        print(name + '\t' + version)
```